# why after clicking my hamburger menu some links disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to add a hamburger functionality to my portfolio website but after hitting the hamburger menu 3 links of my navbar disappeared.

This is my HTML:

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
const navLinks = document.querySelector('nav ul.nav-links');
const socialLinks = document.querySelector('.social');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('menu-open');
});
```

```css
/* hamburger functionality */

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-open .nav-links {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-open .social {
  display: flex;
}

header>nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 23px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--text-hover);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 50px;
  background: none;
}

.social img {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.social img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

@media screen and (max-width:718px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hamburger img {
    width: 35px;
    filter: invert(1);
  }
  .nav-links,
  .social {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--background);
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    /* gap: 30px; */
  }
  .nav-links a {
    color: var(--text-color);
  }
  .nav-links a:hover {
    color: var(--text-hover);
  }
  .social {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-open .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <span><a href="#home">Aditya.</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"><img src="/assets/svg/hamburger.svg" alt="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="social">
      <a href="https://github.com/aditya9-2" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/github.png" alt="github" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/aadityabasak20" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/LinkedIn.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="25" height="25"></a>
      <a href=" https://x.com/aadityaa027?t=QolEyjPnS_MgghSikQeP0g&s=08" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/x.png" alt="x" width="25" height="25"></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The "projects, skills, and contacts" links are not visible in the hamburger functionality.

Result:

[image: this is the result i got after clicking the hamburger, here projects skills and contact links are not visible]

and I am not able to close the hamburger.

This is the closing SVG I want to use:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0,0,256,256">
<g fill="#d5d5d5" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><g transform="scale(5.12,5.12)"><path d="M9.15625,6.3125l-2.84375,2.84375l15.84375,15.84375l-15.9375,15.96875l2.8125,2.8125l15.96875,-15.9375l15.9375,15.9375l2.84375,-2.84375l-15.9375,-15.9375l15.84375,-15.84375l-2.84375,-2.84375l-15.84375,15.84375z"></path></g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The currently shown snippet does not appear to correctly reproduce the issue, I am seeing all four links after clicking the button.

Comment: Your class menu-open is not provided in css and also Why are you using document.body for toggle

Comment: Give those links a background color and you willl see they cover the hamburger once you’ve clicked it, hence it is not seeing subsequent clicks.

Comment: @mehdi, why is putting the class menu-open on body a problem? And that class is used in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code, when you click on the toggle icon for the first time, the open menu overlaps with the toggle icon so a second click is not clickable. I have added space to the top of the open menu so your menus are open and closed, respectively.

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
const navLinks = document.querySelector('nav ul.nav-links');
const socialLinks = document.querySelector('.social');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('menu-open');
});
```

```css
/* hamburger functionality */

.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

.menu-open .nav-links {
    display: flex;
}

.menu-open .social {
    display: flex;
}

header>nav ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 0 23px;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--text-hover);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 50px;
    background: none;
}

.social img {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.social img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

@media screen and (max-width:718px) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hamburger img {
        width: 35px;
        /*            filter: invert(1);*/
    }

    .nav-links,
    .social {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: var(--background);
        padding: 10px 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        margin: 10px 0;
        text-align: center;
        /* gap: 30px; */
    }

    .nav-links a {
        color: var(--text-color);
    }

    .nav-links a:hover {
        color: var(--text-hover);
    }

    .social {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-open .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <span><a href="#home">Aditya.</a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg" alt="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social">
            <a href="https://github.com/aditya9-2" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/github.png" alt="github" width="25" height="25"></a>
            <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/aadityabasak20" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/LinkedIn.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="25" height="25"></a>
            <a href=" https://x.com/aadityaa027?t=QolEyjPnS_MgghSikQeP0g&s=08" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/x.png" alt="x" width="25" height="25"></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I have used the link to the Hamburger icon; please replace yours.